# DbContext class emptied out after changing connection string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I have a EF data model in a class library project.  I changed the connection string in the app config and now my DbContext class is empty. I get build errors that refer to the context class, but its not there.  Its as if the context class was emptied out when I did a build, but the context class was not refreshed. 
Once you create the EF model with a specific connection string, how can you refresh your model after changing the connection string?

[update]
Im using DB-first.

The model was pointing to an instance on a different server and I changed the connection string in the app config.  The db on this other server is where I made the schema changes (added some constraints).

When I update my model, I expand my context class (*.Context.tt) when the .cs file is empty.

I know ive done this a gillion times before, but not so much with changing the connection string at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? Do you have an EDMX file?

Comment: Yes, there is an edmx, but the *.context.cs file was emptied

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DB first EF then use the model viewer to refresh your DB entities.

If it's code first, rebuilding the solution won't have any effect on the DbContext class.